# spring data jpa one-to-one overflow exception

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Entities:

```
Hotel{
 String name;
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 Address addr;
}

Address{
 String street;
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "hotel")
 @JsonIgnore
 Hotel hotel;
}
```

Here is the code to save hotel entity into database:

```
Address addr = new Address("3333 Elvin");
Hotel hotel = new Hotel("someHotel");
addr.setHotel(hotel);
hotel.setAddress(addr);
hotelDao.save(hotel);
```

I got error `"Handler dispatch failed;nestedException:java.lang.stackoverflowerror"`

What's the cause of this error? The code is basically copied from one-to-one tutorial.

Comment: Please show the content of the setters.

Comment: @Kirinya I'm using annotation `@Data` of lombok, so the setter is just `this.x = x`;

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace.